# How to write a linq query or use a storedprocedure to build a json object in MVC4?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Hi all i have a Database where i have some tables named

```
 [Options],[ProductAttributes],[Products],[ProductSKU],[ProductSKUOptionMappings]
```

i had added this as entity model to my project,now i want to write a linq query for this where i can get these column from the above specified tables

based on this stored procedure

```
  ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetProductDetail]
   (
     @ProductID bigint
   )
   as
   begin
   Select P.ProductName,  P.ProductDescription, PA.SKU, PA.OptionId,O.OptionName,  PA.Value, PS.ImageURL from ProductSKU PS 
   INNER JOIN ProductAttributes PA ON PS.SKU = PA.SKU 
   INNER JOIN Products P ON P.ProductId = PS.ProductId
   INNER JOIN Options O ON O.OptionsId = PA.OptionId 
   WHERE PS.ProductId = @ProductID
   end
```

i want to convert this query into linq query or use this as Storedprocedure to get my required Json object

the output of my stored procedure looks like this

```
   ProductName                     ProductDescription        SKU    OptionId    OptionName  Value   ImageURL 
Tactical Long Sleeve Shirts     Hemline side slits        Shirt_1001  1          Color      Grey    C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Images\LongSleeveShirt.jpg
 Tactical Long Sleeve Shirts    Hemline side slits            Shirt_1001  2      Size        S          C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Images\LongSleeveShirt.jpg
 Tactical Long Sleeve Shirts    Hemline side slits            Shirt_1001  3       Fit     Regular   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Images\LongSleeveShirt.jpg
```

each product may have different SKUs like the above so can any one help me here how can i build my json object which looks like this

```
  i want my json object to be in this format

     var productdetails={
"productId": "1",
"productname": "Casualshirts",
"productSkus": [
    {
        "Skuimage": "URL",
        "SKU": [
            {
                "ProducSKU": "Shoe1001",
                "Options": [
                    {
                        "productOptions": [
                            {
                                "OptionID": "1",
                                "optionname": "Color",
                                "value": "Black"
                            },
                            {
                                "OptionID": "2",
                                "optionname": "Size",
                                "value": "S"
                            },
                            {
                                "OptionID": "3",
                                "optionname": "Fit",
                                "value": "Regular"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ProducSKU": "Shoe1002",
                "Options": [
                    {
                        "productOptions": [
                            {
                                "OptionID": "1",
                                "optionname": "Color",
                                "value": "Black"
                            },
                            {
                                "OptionID": "2",
                                "optionname": "Size",
                                "value": "S"
                            },
                            {
                                "OptionID": "3",
                                "optionname": "Fit",
                                "value": "Regular"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ProducSKU": "Shoe1003",
                "Options": [
                    {
                        "productOptions": [
                            {
                                "OptionID": "1",
                                "optionname": "Color",
                                "value": "Black"
                            },
                            {
                                "OptionID": "2",
                                "optionname": "Size",
                                "value": "S"
                            },
                            {
                                "OptionID": "3",
                                "optionname": "Fit",
                                "value": "Regular"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

and here is my model class

```
      public class ProductItems
{
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    public List<productSKU> SKUs { get; set; }
}

public class productSKU
{
    public string productsku { get; set;}
    public string SKUImageURL { get; set;}
    public List<options> oPTIONS { get; set; }
}

public class options
{
    public long OptionID { get; set; }
    public string OptionName { get; set;}
    public string OptionValue { get; set;}
}
```

can any one help me in how to construct my stored procedure or linq query as above json pbjkect thanks in advance...

this is how i am trying to bind my data to my model

```
       public IEnumerable<ProductItems> ProductDeatils(long ProductID)
    {
        var productdeatils = products.ExecuteStoreQuery<ProductItems>("GetProductDetail @ProductID ", new SqlParameter("@ProductID", ProductID));
        var data=new List<ProductItems>();
        foreach (var prod in productdeatils)
        {
            ProductItems items = new ProductItems();
            items.ProductID = prod.ProductID;
            items.ProductName = prod.ProductName;
            items.SKUs
        }

        return data;
    }
```

i am stuck with number of properties in my class and number of Database columns i amn retrieving from my procedure how can i map them to my model

Comment: What you have shown is invalid JSON. Please format your JSON code here: http://jsonlint.com/ This will ensure that you have a valid JSON and properly formatted for StackOverflow.

Comment: could you help me in doing this @DarinDimitrov...i am a bit confused

Comment: I cannot help you with this because you are asking in your question how to obtain the desired JSON result but you have posted **invalid** JSON. So I don't know how to generate such invalid JSON that you are asking.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov i had updated with my validated json object could  you help me now plzzz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have retrieved an instance of your `ProductItems` model from your data layer you could project it into an anonymous object to be passed to a JsonResult in order to achieve the desired JSON structure:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    ProductItems model = ... retrieve the model from your data layer

    var result = new
    {
        productId = model.ProductID,
        productname = model.ProductName,
        productSkus = model.SKUs.Select(sku => new
        {
            Skuimage = sku.SKUImageURL,
            SKU = new[]
            {
                new 
                {
                    ProducSKU = sku.productsku,
                    Options = new[]
                    {
                        new
                        {
                            productOptions = sku.oPTIONS.Select(opt => new
                            {
                                OptionID = opt.OptionID,
                                optionname = opt.OptionName,
                                value = opt.OptionValue
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    };

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: @Darrin Dimitrov.. i am using an apicontroller not an MVCcontroller here can you help me with that

Comment: You could have the following API action: `public HttpResponseMessage Get() { var result = ...same as in my answer...; return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result); }`.

Comment: can u help me binding the retrieved data to my model

Comment: That's no longer related to ASP.NET MVC. It is data retrieval specific and it will very much depend on how you are querying your database. Whether you are using an ORM or plain ADO.NET. Also you should probably try something first and provide your attempts. We are here to help you but not do your job. You will have to try solving it by yourself, show your progress, explaining the difficulties you have encountered, etc... You cannot just post your specifications here and expect that someone will be writing the code for you. It's not how this site is supposed to be used.

Comment: i have been doing my attempts...see my updated question i am stuck there